# Meta data on table scaffolding in dynamic data project

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-data, scaffolding, partial-classes

I created an ASP.NET webapplication with dynamic data. I'm fairly new to this so I'm struggling with alot of things but now I'm completely stuck.

Thing is, I want to hide, lets say, the name column of a table in my database (model based on entity framework). Therefor I added a new folder named "AppCode" (because I cannot add the default app_code folder in a web app) and added a file named "User.cs" The contents of this file look like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User{
}

public class UserMetaData
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object Name;
}
```

Now, after running the application I did not expect to see the name column in the crud pages, but it is still there. What am I missing here?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Make sure your User.cs is in the same namespace as your designer file named YourDataContextHere.designer.cs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already found the solution but could not answer my own question for 8 hours. I will post it tomorrow. Anyhow, the problem was that my model was in another project within the solution. Putting the partial class in that project solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself. What went wrong was the fact that my model was placed in a referenced class library and not in the dynamic data project itself.  It seems to be very important that the namespace of the partial class is the same as that of the model. Otherwise it would not work. So, in my case I had to place the partial class in my "domain" project which contains the model. Hope this helps someone.